# Required input only under certain condition (WordPress/Contact Form 7)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, validation

I have little problem with jQuery script for Contact Form 7. When user choose 'yes', I show inputs and it works, but these inputs have to be required in case of 'yes'. When I add * to inputs by shortcode of WordPress Contact Form 7, I cant send form with empty inputs, which aren't displayed/are hidden(!), so I have tried a lot of methods to make inputs required only in case of 'yes'/be displayed, for example.: show/hide, CSS display none/block, aria-required, property required, class wpcf7-validates-as-required, change value of input, etc. and nothing.

Unfortunately I havent found answer at documentation of Contact Form 7. I hope exists any solution without necessity of create additional custom validation.

I put JS code with all of my ideas - maybe I'm close to find solution.

I just have asked about this at forum related with WordPress and they recommended me to try here.

HTML + shortcodes WPCF7:

```
<div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_inner vc_row-fluidr">
  <p>Would you like something?
  [radio question label_first default:1 "No" "Yes"]</p>
    <div id="add-something">
      <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-md-6 form-column">
        <label>Company name*[text your-company-name]</label>
        <label>City* [text your-city]</label>
        <label>Postal code* <div class="postal-code"><label>[text your-code-city-1 class:kp-1 minlength:2 maxlength:2]</label> - <label>[text your-code-city-2 class:kp-2 minlength:3 maxlength:3]</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS/jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#add-something").hide();
  jQuery("#add-something input").hide();


        jQuery("input[name=question]").change(function(){          

        if (jQuery(this).val() == "Yes") {

        jQuery("#add-something input").show();
        var input = jQuery("#add-something input");
        if (input.length > 0) { //If the input field contains any value remove it
            input.val('');
          }
        jQuery("#add-something").slideDown();
        jQuery("#add-something input").attr("aria-required", "true");
        jQuery("#add-something input").addClass("wpcf7-validates-as-required");
        jQuery("#add-something input").prop('required',true);


        }
        else {
        jQuery("#add-something").slideUp();
        jQuery("#add-something input").hide();
        var input = jQuery("#add-something input");
        input.val("NA"); //add NA Value to hidden field that is required!



        jQuery("#add-something input").attr("aria-required", "false");
        jQuery("#add-something input").removeClass("wpcf7-validates-as-required");
        jQuery("#add-something input").prop('required',false);
        }                                                            
   });
});
```

Any ideas? :-)